# Spring Controller @ResponseBody is Empty

Tags: controller, response, spring-mvc-test

In my spring webapp, I'm trying to test my controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/Position")
public class PositionController {
 @Autowired
PositionRepository positionRepository;

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/search/infoforPosition)
public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> read(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true)    Integer id){                

    List<Map<String, Object>> res = positionRepository.infoPerPosition(id);
    return res;
  } 
 }
```

My test Code looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath*:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
 private MockMvc mockMvc;  
 @Mock
 PositionController PositionMock;
 @Before 
 public void setUp() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(PositionMock).build();
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/Position/search/infoforPosition")
             .param("id", "435651")
             .accept("application/json"))
             .andDo(print())
             .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
        }
```

When i execute the test i got this:

```
     MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = GET
     Request URI = /Position/search/infoforPosition
     Parameters = {id=[435651]}
     Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}

     Handler:
      Type = org.controllers.PositionController
     Method = public java.util.List<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>>   org.controllers.PositionController.read(java.lang.Integer)

           Async:
    Was async started = false
    Async result = null

   Resolved Exception:
            Type = null

     ModelAndView:
       View name = null
            View = null
           Model = null

        FlashMap:

  MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 200
   Error message = null
         Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
    Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
            Body = []
   Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

when i test the url in Chrome Browser i got this:

[{"id":435651,"Position_id":33,"section":64509}]

In my pom.xml file i added jackson-mapper-asl.jar and  jackson-core-asl.jar
I don't know why the response status is 200 but i did'nt got any data,so how the unit test pass?
When i put a breakpoint , it seems like the application doesn't execute the method.

Any help will be much appreciated :)